# Did the LHC just find a Z' boson?

Tags: particle-physics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Did the guys at Fermilab find a fifth force?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8248/did-the-guys-at-fermilab-find-a-fifth-force)

Did the LHC just find a Z' boson, or is it just your typical media overblown sensationalism with no basis in fact?

Comment: Did you mean Fermilab? If so, see http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8248/did-the-guys-at-fermilab-find-a-fifth-force (and if not, no, the LHC hasn't found anything interesting lately as far as I know)

Comment: Takahashi - can you provide a link to such "typical media overblown sensationalism"?